# Spyne - How do I accept key value pairs in a SOAP endpoint?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, python-3.6, spyne

I'm trying to build a `SOAP` service and I want to pass something like below to an endpoint.

```
    <payload>
        <initiation_date>2019-05-17T00:00:00.000</initiation_date>
        <facility_num>123</facility_num>
        <order_num>123</order_num>
    </payload>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is get is a `dict` in my endpoint.

My endpoint looks like this:

```
class SoapService(ServiceBase):

    @rpc(Unicode, Unicode, Unicode, Array(Unicode), _returns=String)
        def soap_service(self, email, password, action, payload):
```

What I need in my `soap_service` endpoint is something like:

```
payload = {
              'initiation_date': '2019-05-17T00:00:00.000',
              'facility_num': '123',
              'order_num': '123'
          }
```

How do I achieve this?

I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you try this with AnyDict type?

Comment: Yes I'd figured that out yesterday. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured, I just had to change my payload `type` in the decorator to `AnyDict`.

This works:

```
@rpc(Unicode, Unicode, Unicode, AnyDict, _returns=String)
        def soap_service(self, email, password, action, payload):
```

Thanks!